# How to get the working copy size in git?

Tags: git

I want to calculate the total working copy size of my currently checked out branch in git (only versioned files; not ignored files or files not yet a descendant of HEAD). Currently I tried this:

```
$ git ls-files | du -k | cut -f1 | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}'
```

However this takes an insane amount of time and outputs a number that doesn't seem to make sense:

```
29800260
```

I'm not sure what this number is. If there is a faster or more accurate command to do this please let me know.

Comment: `du` doesn't read standard input so it will basically ignore your `git` command and traverse the entire directory tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right path, but use backticks instead of pipe.

```
du -k `git ls-files` | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}'
```

If you have to worry about whitespace, both `git ls-files` and `xargs` can talk in nulls:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 du -k | awk '{total += $1} END {print total}'
```

It took so long for you because `git ls-files |` was essentially a no-op, and `du -k |` was piping output for every file from your current directory down.  Exactly what you were trying to avoid!

Comment: This breaks if there are spaces in the path. How can I make it work with spaces? Example: `Subdir/With Spaces/file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Note that `du` shows the amount of disk space that a file takes up. This may vary depending on the file system type and settings. For example, a small 1 byte file may take up a block of 4 KB, or its content may be stored inline with the metadata.

If you want a sum of the exact byte sizes of all the files in the repository instead, you can use this:

```
git ls-tree -r -l HEAD | cut -d' ' -f 4- | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%.0f\n", s}'
```

This uses the blob size that is stored in Git and also works on a bare repository. The result is typically smaller than the one from `du`.